# fatal error: android_native_app_glue.h: No such file or directory

Tags: android, c++, eclipse, android-ndk

So, I can't stop receiving an error message

> fatal error: android_native_app_glue.h: No such file or directory

while trying to compile an application. It's really freaking me out. I've already specified the path to **android_native_app_glue** in project settings, but it makes no sense. What else can I do?

*(OS Windows 7)*

the make file looks like

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := droidblaster
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := Main.cpp EventLoop.cpp Log.cpp
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -landroid -llog
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := android_native_app_glue

$(call import-module,android/native_app_glue)

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Comment: Worked for me: LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := cpufeatures android_native_app_glue ndk_helper

Answer (score 1):

I think you can fix it this way:
Try first calling:

```
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

and after that

```
$(call import-module,android/native_app_glue)
```

like this:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := droidblaster
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := Main.cpp EventLoop.cpp Log.cpp
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -landroid -llog
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := cpufeatures
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += android_native_app_glue
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += ndk_helper

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY) 

$(call import-module,android/native_app_glue)
```

but maybe you just forgot to include it in your files?

Comment: Nope, still the same result. It says:

`21:36:01 **** Auto Build of configuration Default for project DroidBlaster ****
ndk-build.cmd all 
"Compile++ thumb : droidblaster <= Main.cpp
In file included from jni/Main.cpp:1:0:
jni/EventLoop.hpp:5:38: fatal error: android_native_app_glue.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs/droidblaster/Main.o] Error 1

21:36:01 Build Finished (took 693ms)`

Comment: also, how could I include it properly? I have #include <android_native_app_glue.h> in EventLoop.hpp.

Comment: thats right - as far as i can see.. but have a look at the native-activity example in the folder: PATH_TO_NDK/samples/native-activity this is working fine and is with native_app_glue

Comment: An error appears when I convert project to C++ project. Thats what book says. Is it really necessary?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably very late
make file is not pointing to right lib
use

```
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := android_native_app_glue
```

which is missed in [Malte Schmitz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1683939/malte-schmitz) 's answer

you can also refer

> android-ndk-folder\sources\android\native_app_glue\Android.mk

Please refer the sample sources given in the NDK

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := cpufeatures android_native_app_glue ndk_helper
```

Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If it's useful for someone, you need to include the path /path/to/android-ndk/sources/android/native_app_glue in Project Properties -> C/C++ General -> Paths and Symbols (over GNU C and GNU C++ language items)